# Query Hive database using Spark Java API

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have a hive database in Hadoop. I am trying to query it using Spark API using JAVA but have not been able to find a good tutorial. Can anyone guide me towards the right direction?

**Edit:** Im using Spark version 1.6.2

So far, i've tried:

```
final SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("spark://my.url.to.Hue:8888");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new  SQLContext(sc);
DataFrame df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM mytableinHive");
```

I feel like my URL set on the master is wrong but I am not sure what value should go in there

Comment: I dont think this doc works for older versions. Im using version 1.6.2

Comment: Ok, here's 1.6.2 - https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables